# Reactive form w/ 2 radio buttons is causing multiple duplicate outputs in console

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form which has a formArray with multiple formGroups which includes 2 radio buttons and 3 number inputs.  I have noticed when I use my custom validator and I console.log the control that is being passed, when I click one of the 2 radio buttons multiple duplicate formControls are displaying in the console when I would think it would only be one.  The weirdest thing is if I select one radio button then the console shows 2 of the same formControls and if I click the other radio button I get 3 of the same formControls.

If I just use the number user input I only get one console.log with the form control (which is what I would think would happen).

I only have a custom validator on one user input so I am not even sure why clicking the radio button is triggering the validation.  I have also noticed this in other scenarios involving observables where if I subscribe to a formGroup for statusChange and I click one of the radio buttons multiple duplicate controls show up in the console and sometimes if I use one number input it also shows multiple controls in the console but if I user other number inputs it correctly only shows one control in the console.

In my code I still need to do some refactoring but you will see I am subscribing 3 times when I build my formGroup.  This would explain why it fires so many times however if I comment out 2 out of the 3 subscriptions and I am only listening to something like valueChange and I select radio button's it's still firing in the console twice at least.  My only thought is it's firing for one radio button that is becoming unselected and then firing for the new radio button that was just selected?

What should happen is on page load both radio buttons are unselected and one field is disabled.  Once a radio button is selected it should enable that field and perform validation on it

I'm getting all twisted around so if anyone can provide any insight it would be much appreciated.  You can check it out [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-zgqvgd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fround-input%2Fround-input.component.ts) (beware I am right in the middle of it, there is a lot left to be done and refactored)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Eric I will try to bring some clearance around why you have so many logs, coming from your custom validator function.

Here is your code with explanations what is triggering what

````
    roundFormGroup.controls.roundSelection.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      // on radio btn change clear out the values for round score
      /**
       * NOTE: 1
       * Whenever a new value is set and if the control is enabled, updateValueAndValidity is being triggered
       * Check this url: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/3a647a5106de3a48f904e338ea046043d143d43a/packages/forms/src/model/form_control.ts#L453
       */
      roundFormGroup.controls.userRoundScore.setValue(null);

      if (this.calcBtnDisabled === false) {
        this.calcBtnDisabled = true;
      }

      if (value === 9 || value === 18) {
        
        /**
         * NOTE: 2
         * Whenver a control is being enabled it's value and validity is being checked
         * Check this url: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/3a647a5106de3a48f904e338ea046043d143d43a/packages/forms/src/model/abstract_model.ts#L979
         */
        roundFormGroup.controls.userRoundScore.enable();
        
        roundFormGroup.controls.userRoundScore.setValidators([
          Validators.required,
          Validators.min(value),
          this.roundInputValidation(value),
        ]);
      }

      // onlySelf is an optional parameter which only runs updateValueAndValidity for this specific control
      // since we are only setting validators for userRoundScore we only need to update validation runs for this control


      /**
       * NOTE: 3
       * You can check the implementation of updateValueAndValidity, which triggers the re-evaluation of the validators
       * Check this url: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/3a647a5106de3a48f904e338ea046043d143d43a/packages/forms/src/model/abstract_model.ts#L1051
       */
      roundFormGroup.controls.userRoundScore.updateValueAndValidity({
        onlySelf: true,
      });


      /**
       * NOTE: 4
       * The last log of the control comes from the usage of template validator together with your validator defined inside the .ts file check
       * ```
       * <input
       * ...
       * [min]="getMinScore(round.get('roundSelection')?.value)"
       * />
       * ```
       * Inside the template the value passed for `min` is changed, which triggeres the onChanges hook of the MinValidator form control, which triggers the updateValueAndValidty for the control on which it is attached (in your case `round selection`)
       */
    });
````

In order to reduce the numbers of validator calls, I would recommend you the following things.

1. Remove the validator for `min` value from the template (NOTE 4)
2. Add check to your `userRoundScore` control, to enable it only when it is disabled (e.g. only the first time)
3. Instead of clearing (by setting) the value inside `userRoundScore` you can show an error message and the user clear it, but this is suggestion might not comply with the businsee requirements, so take it with grain of salt.

You can check this modifed stackblitz with notes and some usefull logs here: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-zgqvgd-gp4tdh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fround-input%2Fround-input.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fround-input%2Fround-input.component.html)